# reassignment to val in scala when trying to update an object

Tags: scala

I'm trying to add an object to a sub list (thirdList) in scala so I have a first loop where I loop on the first object and a second loop where I loop on a second sub list when finding the object I try to add my new object to a list (thirdList) this is my code:

```
        if (!firstList.isEmpty) {
          for (firstObject <- firstList) {
            if (firstObject.rank == firstObjectRank) {
              println("ok")
              var secondList = firstObject.secondList
              if (!secondList.isEmpty) {
                for (secondObject <- secondList) {
                  if (secondObject.rank == secondObjectRank) {
                    println("ok 2")
secondObject.thirdList = secondObject.thirdList :+ myNewObject
                  } else {
                    println("secondObject not found")
                  }
                }
              }
            } else {
              println("firstObject not found")
            }
          }
        } else {
          println("firstList is empty")
        }
```

Here is my structure:

```
{
"firstList": [
{ "firstObject" : "ObjectFirstList"},
{
"secondList" : [
{"secondObject" : "ObjectSecondList"},
"thirdList" : [
{"thirdObject" : "ObjectThirdList"}
]
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: The member `thirdList` om `secondObject` is a `val`. You can only assign a value to a `val` once; you cannot modify it as you are trying to do in the line `secondObject.thirdList = secondObject.thirdList :+ myNewObject`

Comment: and then how can I modify my object or push my newObject to a thirdList?

Comment: Make it a `var` instead of a `val`, for example.

Comment: I'm a little confused and I'm new to all of this can you give an example please? I tried to use a copy of my object and it did not work

Comment: What is the type of `secondObject` (the class)?

Comment: an object that contains: case class secondObject(
    rank: Int,
    title: String,
    average: Double,
    thirdList: Seq[thirdResult])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional languages, like Scala, you should use **values** and **immutable data structures**. They cannot be updated, which leads to many useful characteristics - explanation of such is beyond this question.

Keyword `val` represents value. Once assigned, you cannot reassign to it, i.e. use `=` operator again:

```
secondObject.thirdList = {...}
```

Keyword `var` represents variable. You can reassign to it freely.
As a side note, variables and values (in other languages known as constants) in Scala intentionally differ by one character in order to encourage people to use the latter.

To be thorough I should mention that `List` in Scala is immutable, and

```
secondObject.thirdList :+ myNewObject
```

returns a new object rather than updating existing one

Enough with theory. Your class definition probably looks something like this:

```
class A {
  val thirdList = List()
}
```

Notice that you assigned something to val with `=`

You have 2 options here:

1. Replace `val` with `var` - your snippet will work as is because `var` allow reassignment
2. Replace `List` with some mutable data structure, i.e. `MutableList`. 
   At this point your code still won't work because mutation of structure and reassignment to value are two different things. Usage of `=` is still illegal. You can instead replace whole line with

   ```
   secondObject.thirdList += myNewObject
   ```

   Second options is better IMHO.

BTW your code can be greatly shortened with the power of Scala Collections. Take a look at them, for example start with:

```
firstList.find(object => object.rank == firstObjectRank).map(_.secondList).find(object => object.rank == secondObjectRank)
```